# Problem with \addtocounter that doen't affect \label

Tags: counters, labels, reftex

I've a little issue with `\label`. here's the code:

```
\chapter{previous chapter}

\phantomsection
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\Alph{chapter}~~ the chapter}
\label{chap:thechapter}

\chapter{next chapter}
```

and then in another part of the document I use: `\ref{chap:thechapter}`
The problem is that it doesn't give the correct number, but the one of the previous chapter. Like if the command `\addtocounter` had an effect only on `\addcontentsline` but not on `\label`. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `\addcontentsline` doesn't issue the command that a \label` can "attach" to.  only `\chapter` (and similar commands, like `\section` or `\caption`) does that, so your label will contain the value from the previous such "anchor point".

Comment: Use `\refstepcounter{chapter}`.

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
\tableofcontents
\chapter{previous chapter}

\phantomsection
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\Alph{chapter}~~ the chapter}
\label{chap:\thechapter}

\chapter{next chapter}
see chapter~\ref{chap:2}
```